# Parse.Cloud multiple success function called

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, parse-platform

I'm developing an photo app and i'm codin a Parse.Cloud procedure to update any categories whith photo type count..

example:

animals -> 300 photos
toys -> 350 photos 
etc..

this is the cloud code

```
Parse.Cloud.define("updateCategoriesCount", function(request,response){
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
var queryCategory = new Parse.Query("categories");
queryCategory.find({
    success: function(categories){
        for (category in categories){
            var queryRecipes = new Parse.Query("photos");
            queryRecipes.equalTo("categoryObj",category);
            queryRecipes.count({
                success: function(count){
                    category.set("count",count);
                    category.save();
                },
                error: function(error){
                    response.error("Error on counting photos for category");
                }
            });

        }
    },
    error: function(error){}
});
```

});

but when call the function the logs are:

Input: {}
  Failed with: Error: Can't call success/error multiple times
    at Object.error (:106:9)
    at Object.queryPhotos.count.error (main.js:196:16)
    at Parse.js:2:7842
    at f (Parse.js:2:6754)
    at Parse.js:2:6246
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.x.each.x.forEach [as _arrayEach] (Parse.js:1:664)
    at c.extend.reject (Parse.js:2:6199)
    at f (Parse.js:2:6949)
    at Parse.js:2:6246

How can solve this problem?

thanks all :D

Answer (score 1):

Your error handler is getting called multiple times, so you should attempt to discover what is causing the error. Instead of

```
response.error("some error string");
```

use

```
response.error(error.message);
```

so you can check your Parse.com logs and see what's happening. Remember that the .count() function is asynchronous, which means it will get called multiple times no matter how many of them fail or succeed. You'd be better off using promises here, but let's see what the error is first...